# How could I get access token for another user (from my app)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like post some message as another user (not currently using the app). Is it possible? Of course, I would like use user which allow to get access my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user goes to your app, you can ask him for the extended permissions 'offline_access' and 'publish_stream'. With these permissions, you should be able to post as that user, even if he is not currently visiting the app.
More info about extended permissions can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

edit:

> You can publish to the Facebook graph
>   by issuing HTTP POST requests to the
>   appropriate connection URLs, using an
>   access token on behalf of the user or
>   an application access token (for Open
>   Graph Pages). For example, you can
>   post a new wall post on Arjun's wall
>   by issuing a POST request to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
      -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
      https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

so basically you retrieve the access token when the user authorizes your application, and store it for later use.

Quote found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: thx for answer, I am quite familiar with that permissions, but I can't find any example, how I could login AS target user. Please help if you know some.

Comment: Thx again, but I should use access token which doesn't expire, how to get one?

Comment: If the user grants you offline_access, the access token you receive by the standard oAuth flow will not expire (unless the user changes his password).

Comment: Ok I have access token for my one user, but when another user want use it i got `OAuthException" ["message"]=> string(72) "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" }`

Comment: Bit hard to judge what's the exact problem, but it sounds a bit like the one user didn't grant the 2 permissions I mentioned. If you pinpoint the problem, consider making a new question.

Comment: For Both users, application has offline_access and publish_stream , but they can't post post on their walls (or rather, fan page wall) :(